# problem in changing java file into an android

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I have a java project which is been created in netbeans, now i am trying to change it to be an android project in eclipse but it shows lots of errors. Can an one pls help me in debing the errors

```
public abstract class BaseOutputAudioDevice extends AudioDeviceBase {
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BaseOutputAudioDevice.class.getName());

protected int position = 0;
protected int freq;
protected int channels;
protected int samplesPerMillisecond;
protected boolean init = false;
protected SampleProcessor processor;

public BaseOutputAudioDevice(SampleProcessor processor) {
    this.processor = processor;
}

@Override
protected void openImpl() throws JavaLayerException {
    super.openImpl();
}

@Override
protected void writeImpl(short[] samples, int offs, int len) throws JavaLayerException {
    if(!init)
    {
        log.log(Level.INFO, "number of channels: " + getDecoder().getOutputChannels());
        log.log(Level.INFO, "number of samples: " + getDecoder().getOutputFrequency());
        freq = getDecoder().getOutputFrequency();
        channels = getDecoder().getOutputChannels();
        samplesPerMillisecond = (freq * channels)/1000;
        log.log(Level.INFO, "samples/ms: " + samplesPerMillisecond);
        log.log(Level.INFO, "buffer length: " + len);
        if(processor != null)
            processor.init(freq, channels);
        init = true;
    }
    position += len/samplesPerMillisecond;

    outputImpl(samples, offs, len);
}

protected abstract void outputImpl(short[] samples, int offs, int len) throws JavaLayerException;

/**
 * Retrieves the current playback position in milliseconds.
*/
public int getPosition() {
    log.log(Level.FINE, "position: " + position + "ms");
    return position;
}

public SampleProcessor getProcessor() {
    return processor;
}

public void setProcessor(SampleProcessor processor) {
    this.processor = processor;
}
}
```

*Edit*

It shows errors in following lines

```
log.log(Level.INFO, "number of channels: " + getDecoder().getOutputChannels());
log.log(Level.INFO, "number of samples: " + getDecoder().getOutputFrequency());
freq = getDecoder().getOutputFrequency();
channels = getDecoder().getOutputChannels();
```

Comment: And what are the errors?

Comment: Sorry. It shows the errors in the following lines  log.log(Level.INFO, "number of channels: " + getDecoder().getOutputChannels());
        log.log(Level.INFO, "number of samples: " + getDecoder().getOutputFrequency());
        freq = getDecoder().getOutputFrequency();
        channels = getDecoder().getOutputChannels();

Comment: And what are the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to work with libraries that do not exist on Android.
For example, your log.log lines look suspiciously like a Log4J call. 
You need to isolate these lines and work with their Android equivalent. 
In the Log4J example - try working with the Android logger instead.